# pthread sleep linux

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am creating a program with multiple threads using pthreads.

Is `sleep()` causing the process (all the threads) to stop executing or just the thread where I am calling `sleep`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just the thread.  The [POSIX documentation for sleep()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) says:

> The `sleep()` function shall cause the calling **thread** to be suspended from execution...

Comment: Here's what "man 3 sleep" says: "sleep() makes the calling process sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed..." (Ubuntu 10). The function is in unistd.h. Is this documentation wrong or is there a second sleep function?

Comment: @user48956: For historical reasons, the man pages often use "process" where the behaviour now applies to the "thread" - this is the case in the `sleep(3)` man page that you refer to.  I suggest submitting a bug to Ubuntu about the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Try this,

```
#include <unistd.h>

usleep(microseconds);
```

Comment: Yep, that's easier to use than `nanosleep` in most cases.

Comment: Note that usleep() is obsolete and has been removed from POSIX.1-2008. You should use either sleep(), or nanosleep() if higher resolution is required.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use [nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/nanosleep.html) and it works fine.
Nanosleep supends the execution of the calling thread. I have had the same doubt because in some man pages sleep refers to the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, there are few cases where you just want to sleep for a small delay (milliseconds). For Linux, read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), and see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725803/841108). For a delay of more than a second, see [sleep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), for a small delay, see [nanosleep(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html). (A counter example might be a [RasPerryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/) running some embedded Linux and driving a robot; in such case you might indeed read from some hardware device every tenth of seconds). Of course what is sleeping is just a single kernel-scheduled task (so a process or thread).

It is likely that you want to code some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). In such a case, you probably want something like [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), or you want to use condition variables (read a [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) about `pthread_cond_init` etc...) associated with mutexes.

Threads are expensive resources (since each needs a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), often of a megabyte at least). You should prefer having one or a few event loops instead of having thousands of threads.

If you are coding for Linux, read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

Posix sleep function is not thread safe.
https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/concurrency/mt-unsafe.html

Answer (score -5):

`sleep()` function does not cease a specific thread, but it stops the whole process for the specified amount of time. For stopping the execution of a particular thread, we can use one pthread condition object and use `pthread_cond_timedwait()` function for making the thread wait for a specific amount of time. Each thread will have its own condition object and it will never receive a signal from any other thread.

Comment: This is inaccurate. The `sleep()` will cause the current thread to sleep. See `sleep(3)`. Lots of older man pages still use the word "process," but in reality a thread is a process.