# Does calling sleep() from pthread put thread to sleep or process?

Tags: c, pthreads, sleep

I saw that there is a question about [pthread sleep linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633089/pthread-sleep-linux)

However, when I looked up the man page on my Linux machine, I see the following:

> SYNOPSIS
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ```
>    unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
> sleep()  makes  the  current  process sleep until seconds seconds
> have elapsed or a
> signal arrives which is not ignored.

So my question is that I would like to know which man page I should follow to put the thread sleep? In addition, if both are true, how can I control that?

I can probably write some code to test it but I want to make sure to hear some feedback from other people as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wording in your man page is likely wrong. Trust the standard and trust **[the man page on kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sleep.3.html)**. Write to the maintainer of the documentation for your distro and tell them to update the manual pages.

Comment: +1 for updating your answer to point to kernel.org. Retracting my answer which did the same. However, as for "trust the standard": only do that after reading the Linux docs, since Linux sometimes deliberately deviates from POSIX behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will do what you suggested.

Comment: Better yet - write to the maintainer of the of the above code and ask them to fix the bug and conform to POSIX

Answer (score 1):

There are two man pages regarding sleep function on my Linux box:

```
$ man -k sleep
sleep (3)   - Sleep for the specified number of seconds
sleep (3p)  - suspend execution for an interval of time
```

The 1st one says "the current process" as does yours.
The 2nd one says "the calling thread" but its preamble states:

> This  manual  page is part of the POSIX Programmer’s Manual.  The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the corresponding Linux manual page for
>          details of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.

So i conclude that `sleep(3)` describes the actual behaviour and `sleep(3p)` is only there for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The man page referenced by @cnicutar says that `sleep` is *not* thread-safe (maybe that's new since 2011?). Interestingly, Dave Butenhof's 1997 book ('Programming with Posix Threads') does include an example which sleeps a thread with `sleep` (p18). [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.programming.threads/Rf98UQI79oE) is an old thread (the other sort) on comp.programming.threads in which Butenhof and others discuss `nanosleep` in the context of pthreads.

In short, `nanosleep` is, I think, Ok, but `sleep` isn't. The `nanosleep` man page at kernel.org doesn't say whether `nanosleep` is thread-safe, but the [gcc sleeping docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) say that it is.