# sleep behaviors in pthread

Tags: linux, pthreads, sleep

I have a question regarding using `sleep()` in a thread created via `pthread_create()` on mainline (vanilla) `Linux (kernel 2.6.18`)

Suppose I create 2 threads whose execution codes are as follows:

```
thread1(void *){
 while (1) {
    sleep(5);
 }
}

thread2(void *){
 while (1) {
    sleep(9);
 }
}
```

My question is whether the `sleep()` in one thread will interfere with the `sleep()` in another thread, for example, if `thread1` wakes up from `sleep()`, will `thread2` be waken **prematurely** as well?

I tried my code on `CentOS 5.4`, and it seems the `sleep()` in each thread is independent of another.

However, I am not sure if this independence is guaranteed. The underlining implementation of `sleep()` should rely on some signals, say `SIGALARM`, and I don't know if it is well defined that which thread gets a signal when the signal arrives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthread sleep linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633089/pthread-sleep-linux)

Comment: OT: It should be `void * threadX(void *);` btw.