# does these code leak memory(construct stl list in an infinite loop)?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl

i made a example program to study whether difining numerous stl object in a local way will leak memory or out of the stack size .
"g_list" is a global list and absorbs some elements from other thread.please do not care about the thread mutex,locks or other thing(because mutex and lock are always attracting,aren't they?),just pay attation to this line "list rawDataList = g_list",in this loop ,a list is constructed each time but never get out of it's scope because it is in a infinite loop.

- here is no "new " for rawDataList,it is a local variable and not dynamic allocated,i mean the list itself,not the elements in it ;
- we know well that "clear" and "pop_front" will destroy elements inside the list
- i run this snippet of code for 7 hours and watch it by the top tool, the memory amount is quite steady and show no sign of leak
  my question:
- every time we construct by call "list rawDataList" and even assign some thing to it but the constructed list will never get out of scope so will never be destroyed,though it's element get destroyed in each loop,but the list object reside in the memory(stack area) all the time,how can the stack contain so many objects when we loops for million times?
- and,when "list rawDataList = g_list" is performed the second time,where goes the list object constructed in the firs time (they have the same name "rawDataList")?
- why doesn't the memory get leaked for this program.

Here are codes:

```
    element e;  
    printf("in Cstlmem2::svc \n");
    int i =0;
    while(1){   
          pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
          while (g_list.empty()) // 为空，等待信号
          {
              pthread_cond_wait(&m_cond,&m_mutex);
          }

          list<element> rawDataList = g_list;
          g_list.clear();
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);

        while (!rawDataList.empty())
        {
            e = rawDataList.front();
            rawDataList.pop_front();

            int i = 0;
            while(i <1000000){
                i++;
            }

            printf("working in Cstlmem2::svc \n");
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea.  I do know that any respectable compiler will unceremoniously delete your "delay loop" (the `while (i < 1000000)`).

Comment: tks,these code has no meaning other than help me to make sure my question. i just do not want this thread running too faster than the thread putting things to g_list.but sleep() only will idle for at least > 1 second which is too much for me. any way,let 's do not look at these inessential code

Comment: Use [`sleep()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3633101/332733) to delay on posix platforms if you need to, don't depend on that loop. If you need a spin-lock there are already ones implemented for each platform that will work. If you need smaller than a second [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) is your best bet.

Comment: @ Mgetz,thanks really!even it is not my main focus for this post.

Comment: This program copies `g_list` into `rawDataList`, and then deletes it. This could be done much more efficiently with a `swap`: `list<element> rawDataList; g_list.swap(rawDataList);`.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `rawDataList` ends whenever the infinite loop repeats. The old list is destroyed. On the next iteration, a new one is created, probably in the same stack slot.

Comment: .tks,your answer is quit reasonble."object defined in an loop will be destroyed in each iteration",i will verify this rule by printing something in a destructor.And i do not think the constructor or operator = can know the existence of an old object under the same name.

Comment: @basketballnewbie Not the same name, no, but the same _memory location_, yes.  Try `list<X> a { X() }; list<X> b { X(); }; a = b;` with an X that logs calls to its constructor and destructor.

Comment: @basketballnewbie ... Or more directly related to what you're doing, change your code to declare `list<element> rawDataList;` above the outer `while` loop, but leave the assignment `rawDataList = g_list;` where it is, and you will see that there still isn't a memory leak.

Comment: @Zack.yes,in my real app,i put "list<element> rawDataList" outside the loop. i intentionally write inside the loop to see if it leak memory.by the way,i do not know why some comment made by you are deleted.....,yet i will try out the scope or variable inside a loop

Comment: @Zack,i tried as you suggest.list<X> a { X() }; list<X> b { X(); }; a = b; result:the assignment a =b won't destroy the old a object,so i tend to believe itis about the scoping.my code:element e;
 element e1;
 e.m_s1 = "s";
 e = e1;
 while(1){
     sleep(1000);
     }
my output:
construct element 
construct element

Answer (score 0):

my answer is:it is about the scoping,the local object is destroyed when leaving its scope.
example code:
               int x =0;
        while (x < 2){
        printf("x is %d \n",x);
        element e1 ;
        x++;

```
    if (2 == x){
         while(1){
            sleep(1000);//do not leave the loop
            }
        }

    }
```

the output(i print something inside the constructor and destructor):
x is 0 
construct element 
destruct ~element     --note:it is before the "x is 1"
x is 1 
construct element

Comment: sorry，it is really Hard to typeset it in a proper way